# How to fix if/else statement

Tags: if-statement

Program won't execute else command

```
print ('This program will determine if three angles can form a triangle')
print ('Enter Angle 1')
degree1=input()

print ('Enter Angle 2')
degree2=input()

print ('Enter Angle 3')
degree3=input ()

degrees= int(degree1+degree2+degree3)

if (degrees>180):
    print ('Yes it does form a triangle as these angles are equal to 180')

else:
    print ('No, it does not form a triangle as these angles are less than 180')
```

Printing Yes it does form a triangle as these angles are equal to 180 regardless of the numerical values entered.

Comment: This is for project assignment: Although it didn't crossover, there are separate lines for each variable and if/else are indented

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check for equality? E.g. `degrees == 180` instead of `degrees>180`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `degree1`,`degree2` and `degree3` are strings than en `+` between them would result in a string concentration *not* an addition. So `10` plus `10` plus `10` would result in a value `"101010"`, converted to int, and then compared to `180`.

You need to convert each `degree` input to an `int` *before* you add them up.

Comment: I changed the degree to an integer...however else is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: @Frank - you need to cast the `input()` to an integer as well.